# How to add the widgets dynamically to column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have added a few widgets inside the  `ListView`. So that I can scroll all widgets. Now I required to add one more widget to the `ListView` to load the list of comments. I can not add the `ListView` inside the `ListView`. And moreover, I do not require the separate scroll for my comments.  It should be scroll along with the widgets inside the `ListView`. So I planned to add the `Column` instead of `ListView`. Could any help to add my comments dynamically in the `Columns`?

```
new Expanded(
          child:
          new ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[

              // Title

              new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10.00, left: 10.00),
                child: new Text(
                  _feed.title, textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
              ),

              // content

              new Container(
                child: new Text(
                  _feed.content, textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
              ),

              // Comments List will go here

            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have the comments data already, simply create a List, then pass it to the `children` property of the `Column`. Something like:

```
var commentWidgets = List<Widget>();
for (var comment in comments) {
  commentWidgets.Add(Text(comment.text)); // TODO: Whatever layout you need for each widget.
}
…

new Expanded(
      child:
      new ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[

          // Title

          new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 10.00, left: 10.00),
            child: new Text(
              _feed.title, textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
          ),

          // content

          new Container(
            child: new Text(
              _feed.content, textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
          ),

          // Comments List will go here
          Column(children: commentWidgets,),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

If you don't have the comments data already and need to fetch it, use a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to build the UI once the future completes.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the FutureBuilder ! It saved my day.

Comment: Hi, I would also like to know how I can dynamically add widget and remove that same widget e.g if say I add a widget how do I target this same widget to remove it?

Answer (score 15):

Another way:

```
return Column(
      children: [
        for(String item in list) Text(item);

    ]);
```

You can also mix static and dynamic fields eaisly in this case:

```
return Column(
          children: [
            for(String item in list) Text(item),
          Text("Static text control"),
   
        ]);
```

Answer (score 7):

By maintaining a reference to the `Column` object, the `.children` field/property can be referenced after the `Column` object has been declared - like so:

```
Column someColumn = Column(
  children: [],
);

someColumn.children.add(Text('Hello 123'));
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently(2021-06), Flutter 2.x implemented null-safe.
The answer from @Gene Bo should work but needs little modification.

This should work.

```dart
var pwdWidgets = <Widget>[];

Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: this.pwdWidgets,
),

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: (){
    setState((){
      this.pwdWidgets.add(Text("Hello World"),);
    });
  },
  child: Text("click me"),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @Derek Lakin's Answer which worked for me too, it is also required to call `setState()`, if you need to update the comments and reload.

```
var commentWidgets = List<Widget>();
for (var comment in comments) {
      commentWidgets.Add(Text(comment.text)); // TODO: Whatever layout you need foreach widget.
}
setState(() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add dynamic child on column widgets.

```
 class CategoriesItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> list;

  const CategoriesItemWidget({Key? key, required this.list})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: list
          .map((string) => Text(string))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginRegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginRegisterPageState createState() => _LoginRegisterPageState();
}

class _LoginRegisterPageState extends State<LoginRegisterPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: new Form(
          child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: createInputs() + createButtons(),
          ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  } 

  List<Widget> createInputs(){
    return{
      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      logo(),
      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
      ),

      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Passwors')
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 20.0), 
    };
  }

  Widget logo(){
      return new Hero(        
        tag:'hero',
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor:Colors.transparent,
          radius: 110.0,
          child: Image.asset("images\logo.PNG"),          
        ),         
        );
    }

    List<Widget> createButtons(){
    return{
      new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text("Login", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
        textColor: Colors.pink,         
        onPressed: () {          
        },
        ),  

        new FlatButton(
        child: new Text("Already not have an account?", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),),
        textColor: Colors.white,         
        onPressed: () {
        }, 
        )  
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.