# Dynamically grow a listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to dynamically grow a listview.

I have tried the code from [How to add the widgets dynamically to column in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605131/how-to-add-the-widgets-dynamically-to-column-in-flutter) but it appears to be outdated and results in an error (List is deprecated).

Here's my code

```
var rowWidget = [];

// grow the list
rowWidget.add(
  Row(
    children: [
      Text('111111'),
    ],
),);

...

// display 
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  children: [
    Container(
      child: Column(
       children: [
         rowWidget,
       ],
     ),
   ),
 ],
),
```

The error which I am getting is `Error: A value of type 'List<Row>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.`

Comment: use List<Row> = [] instead of var rowWidget . I think list is not deprecated only List() constructor deprecated as i remember

Comment: I still get the error ```Error: A value of type 'List<Row>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.```

Comment: List<Widget> = [] and children: <Widget> [] try like this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Var rowWidget = <Row>[];

Also where you add it to the build try

children : rowWidget,

Or

children : [ …rowWidget ],

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is due the fact that you are assigning a list in a place where it expects a single Widget. You are basically providing a nested list:

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  children: [
    Container(
      child: Column(
       children: [
         rowWidget,
       ],
     ),
   ),
 ],
),
```

Should be either:

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  children: [
    Container(
      child: Column(
       children: rowWidget
     ),
   ),
 ],
),
```

or if you want to spread the list, this also works:

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  children: [
    Container(
      child: Column(
       children: [
         ...rowWidget,
       ],
     ),
   ),
 ],
),
```